# Contents inside map doesn't render

Tags: reactjs

when i render this piece of code the `comment` in the `comments` array is not displaying to the component this is a reactjs code

```
    var Board = React.createClass({

       getInitialState: function() {
             return{comments: ['i am rohith','some call me drohi','some call me rogi']}
       }

        render: function() {
        return(
               <div className="board">
                  {
                      this.state.comments.map(function(text,i){
                         return(<Comment key={i}>{text}</Comment>);
                      })
                  }
                </div>
               );
        }


    });
```

when i render this piece of code the string in the comments array is not displaying to the component

Comment: add code for `Comment` component also?

Comment: While trying to fiddle it with "div" instead of "Comment" it works, so please add the "Comment" code

Answer (score 0):

I see the `state` is missing out there and cannot be accessed in render function of your code snippet.

```
this.state.comments
```

I made some changes, see if it helps.
You can tinker around the snippet. **https://codesandbox.io/s/6RxBYqpBQ**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Board extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      comments: ['i am rohith', 'some call me drohi', 'some call me rogi'],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="board">
        {this.state.comments.map(function(text, i) {
          return <span key={i}>{text} <br /></span>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```